# How to exploit strong features but they cover only 10% of data in machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, boosting

Assume we want to develop a machine learning application, for example using XGBoost model, or RandomForest to predict the houses' prices in some states.

We have a set of features such that there are no  missing values at those features for all data points. In addition, we have one more very strong feature. It correlates 90% with the output (houses' price) but only ten percent of data ( true for training and testing data) have information of that feature. We do not have information of that feature for the remaining 90% data point.

We should not discard that feature in XGBoost because 90% of data is missing. If we decide to use that feature, what is the smartest choice to exploit that feature with XGBoost ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not entirely sure how XGB handles NA values... but the most simple solution I would use is to train two different models: one on the set that has a non NA value and the other one (completely without the remaining all NA column of course) without the critical feature...

Comment: Xgboost will automatically fill in null values, and you can set a default fill-in, from the fit options. However, there's no reason to discard the data. One simple solution would be to evaluate the range of the correlated feature, say [0,5], and then set the null placeholder to be -1. That way, the forest can just split on whether the feature is below 0 or above 0, and that way it will take advantage of the feature, or otherwise use a placeholder of -1 for no value.